# Android Studio read data sql not show from KSOAP

Tags: android, web-services, asmx, android-ksoap2

I have program android to read data from SQL Server. I use web service with KSOAP2. When i run the program the result not show in my android application. The result from web service i wanna put in TextView playeringame.

My code in android studio like this

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;


public class StatusServerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/TotalID";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "TotalID";
private static String URL = "http://192.168.200.1/A/WebService.asmx";

TextView total;
Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_status_server);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    TypedValue typedValueColorPrimaryDark = new TypedValue();
    StatusServerActivity.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark, typedValueColorPrimaryDark, true);
    final int colorPrimaryDark = typedValueColorPrimaryDark.data;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
    }
    total =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playeringame);

    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
    HttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransport(URL);
    try
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        int result =  Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
        total.setText(result);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My code in web service like this

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Net.Sockets

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebService
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function TotalID() As Integer
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=RF_User;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim total As Integer
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_rfaccount"), con)
    Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
    myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    myreader.Read()
    If myreader.HasRows Then
        total = myreader.Item("").ToString
    End If
    con.Close()
    Return total
End Function
```

my logcat

```
05-16 17:24:34.192    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:46)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:68)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect.StatusServerActivity.onCreate(StatusServerActivity.java:53)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-16 17:24:34.196    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 17:24:34.252    1550-1550/net.dragon_dev.www.dzoneconnect W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Anyone can help me to solve my error?
thanks before

Comment: First of all, you're making a network request on the main thread, which is bad. Second, did you check whether your catch block catches an exception during the app run?

Comment: network request on the main thread? your catch block catches an exception during the app run? i don't understand about that

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand?

Comment: i just see a lot of tutorial using ksoap2 and also like that and i followed ... and i don't understand why my result from web service not show in my apps

Comment: It's not clear to me what steps you've taken to debug the problem you're facing.

Comment: i already try to change format total.settext() like total.setText(String.valueOf(result)); or total.setText(result); or total.setText(result+""); or total.setText(""+result);